# Set Timeout for item in Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, timeout, parallel.foreach

I'm using Parallel.ForEach to process over an concurrent dictionary collection. ConcurrentDictionary contains Key and Byte field.

concurrentDictionary - is Concurrent Dictionary collection here.

```
Parallel.ForEach(concurentDictionary, (item) =>
{
    var mailObject = dbContext.MailObjects.Where(x=> x.MailObjectId == item.key).Select(y=> y);
    mailObject.MailBody = ConvertToPdf(item.Value.MailBody);
} 
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I want to set timeout if any particular item takes maximum time set say 60 seconds. If it takes more than 60 sec, I would like to exit and not save that particular item. Rest of the items should be saved by `dbContext.SaveChanges()` method. How can this be achieved in Parallel.ForEach?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may approximate what you want.

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions();
parallelOptions.CancellationToken = cts.Token;
parallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = System.Environment.ProcessorCount;

Timer timer = new Timer(callback => { cts.Cancel(); }, null, 60*1000, Timeout.Infinite);

try
{
    Parallel.ForEach(concurentDictionary, parallelOptions, (item) =>
    {
        var mailObject = dbContext.MailObjects.Where(x => x.MailObjectId == item.key).Select(y => y);
        mailObject.MailBody = ConvertToPdf(item.Value.MailBody);
        parallelOptions.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    });
}
catch (OperationCanceledException e)
{
    // Log the cancellation event...
}
finally
{
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
    cts.Dispose();
}
```

Here's a complete revision of the solution that scopes a timer for each iteration. Instead of a cancellation token, it leverages loopstate to stop the iterations should one (or more) exceed the time limit. This does not rely on an exception to exit the loop. However, as this is written, any exception will also trigger all loops to stop. Note that this doesn't immediately stop all loops and will complete execution of existing loops until they also complete or timeout.

```
{
    if (Parallel.ForEach(concurentDictionary, (item, loopState) =>
        {
            Timer timer = new Timer(callback => { loopState.Stop(); }, null, 60 * 1000, Timeout.Infinite);

            try
            {
                if (loopState.ShouldExitCurrentIteration || loopState.IsExceptional)
                    loopState.Stop();

                var mailObject = dbContext.MailObjects.Where(x => x.MailObjectId == item.key).Select(y => y);
                mailObject.MailBody = ConvertToPdf(item.Value.MailBody);

                if (loopState.ShouldExitCurrentIteration || loopState.IsExceptional)
                    loopState.Stop();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                loopState.Stop();
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                timer.Dispose();
            }
        }
    ).IsCompleted)
    {
        // All events complete
    }

}
catch (AggregateException)
{
    // Execution will not get to this point until all of the iterations have completed (or one 
    // has failed, and all that were running when that failure occurred complete).
}
```

Comment: Or as I re-read your question, this may not. It sounds as if you want a cancellation if any one item takes longer than 60 seconds. In that case, you could scope a new timer for each parallel loop with the same callback.

Comment: You mean Timer inside parallel.ForEach. Can you please show me how? Thanks